# How to display the time of sadf in epoch format

Tags: ubuntu, centos, timestamps, sysstat

I have a problem in sadf between ubuntu and centos. The thing is how the date is displayed in both.

Ubuntu:

```
root@db1:/usr/local/nagios/libexec/nrpe_local# sadf | head -10
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us  300   2014-05-15 03-05-01 UTC all     %%user  0.14
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us  300   2014-05-15 03-05-01 UTC all     %%nice  0.00
```

Centos:

```
[root@ui1 jboss]# sadf | head -5
ui1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us    595     1400123401      all     %user   1.00
ui1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us    595     1400123401      all     %nice   0.00
```

I need to display time in ubuntu as it's displayed in centos (epoch time).

I haven't have lucky to find some configuration file that could fix this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check `sadf` manpage to know exactly what option will show seconds since epoch time, There is a difference between versions of `sysstat`.

With my Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS:

```
$ sadf -V
sysstat version 10.0.3
(C) Sebastien Godard (sysstat <at> orange.fr)
```

With this version, option to show epoch time is `-T`:

```
-T     Display timestamp (UTC - Coordinated Universal Time) in  seconds
       from the epoch.
```

But with [sysstat 8.1.2-2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/sadf.1.html), this option is `-D`.

```
-D     This  option  is  equivalent to option -d below, except that the
       timestamp  is  always  expressed  in  seconds  since  the  epoch
       (00:00:00 UTC 01/01/1970).
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for whatever strange reason, the flag suggested by Gnouc doesn't exist on your system, you can always use `date` to parse the `sadf` output and convert to epoch time:

```
$ sadf | perl -plae '/.+? .+? (.+?) (.+?)/; $d=$1; $t=$2; $d=~s/-/\//g; 
                    $t=~s/-/:/g; $k=`date -d "$d $t $F[4]" +%s`; chomp($k); 
                    s/$F[2] $F[3] $F[4]/$k/'
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us  300   1400205600 all     %%user  0.14
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us  300   1400205600 all     %%nice  0.00
```

or, if you don't need to keep the format exactly but can loose some whitespace:

```
$ sadf | while read a b date time zone rest; do 
    date=$(date -d "${date//-//} ${time//-/:} $zone" +%s); 
    printf "%s %s %s %s\n" "$a" "$b" "$date" "$rest"; 
 done
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us 300 1400123101 all     %%user  0.14
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us 300 1400123101 all     %%nice  0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu the option that worked for me is -T:

`root@db1:/usr/local/nagios/libexec/nrpe_local# sadf -T | head -10
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us    300     1400123101      all     %%user  0.14
db1.oas3.realmedia.xstrat.us    300     1400123101      all     %%nice  0.00`

Thanks a lot!